Need Help with DIY Phase sequence meter
I have seen this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyrhW_gnQEM and I am really interested in creating DIY version of this for induction motor. Surfed through internet, but could not anything apart from this image

But I am not able to figure our where the 9V battery will connect to this and how to make this work like for the motor shown in the video. Please help me out to create a small version of this. Help me with any source or material if you all can.
